# Windows Authentication With WMI

Tags: windows, wmi, credentials

I want to use Windows current credential when using WMI to query data on a remote machine, but in many  examples I found that I have to use Connection object which needs you to provide a username, password and authority for validating username and password as shown below:

```
            Dim connection As New ConnectionOptions
            connection.Username = userNameBox.Text
            connection.Password = passwordBox.Text
            connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:MyDomain"

            Dim scope As New ManagementScope( _
                "\\RemoteMachine\root\CIMV2", connection)
            scope.Connect()
```

I want to bypass these inputs and use current Windows logon credentials instead, is there any way for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here' the C# example with connnection options using Windows credentials.

```
ConnectionOptions connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions
{
    Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy,
    Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
};
```